Rewriting cookies to local storage in React and Next
A project consists of 4 sources. In this project, I want to rewrite the cookie to local storage. I have implemented it in the user source, and it is correctly saved in local storage. However, in the landing source, I have not been able to retrieve the token in local storage despite making changes. The important point is that when I log in to the user, it should automatically log in to the landing as well.Below, I have attached the files for the landing source.
main.js
import { useContext, createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
// import { setCookie } from 'cookies-next'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { useLogout } from '@/core/services/react-query/auth'

const context = createContext()

export const useMainContext = () => {
    return useContext(context)
}

const MainContextProvider = ({
    children,
    theme: initialTheme,
    token: _token,
  
}) => {
    const [theme, _setTheme] = useState(initialTheme)
    const [token, _setToken] = useState(_token)
    
    const [isOpen, _setIsOpen] = useState(false)

    const router = useRouter()
    const { pathname, asPath, query, locale } = router

    useEffect(() => {  
        const storedTokenFromCookies = document.cookie  
            .split('; ')  
            .find(row => row.startsWith('token='));  
        
        if (storedTokenFromCookies) {  
            const tokenValue = storedTokenFromCookies.split('=')[1];  
            setToken(tokenValue);  // Set token in the state  
            localStorage.setItem('token', tokenValue);  // Also set it in localStorage  
            console.log('User found in cookies:', tokenValue);  

            // Redirect user to profile page  
            router.push('/profile');  
        } else {  
            const storedToken = localStorage.getItem('token');  
            if (storedToken) {  
                setToken(storedToken);  // Update state if the token exists in localStorage  
            }  
        }  
    }, [router]);  

    const toggleTheme = () => {
        const value = theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark'
        // setCookie('theme', value)
        localStorage.setItem('theme', value)
        _setTheme(value)

        if (value === 'dark') 
        {document.documentElement.classList.add('dark')
        }else {document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')}
    }

    const toggleLang = () => {
        const lang = locale === 'en' ? 'fa' : 'en'
        router.push({ pathname, query }, asPath, { locale: lang })
        document.documentElement.setAttribute(
            'dir',
            lang === 'en' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl'
        )
        // setCookie('lang', lang, { path: '/' })
        localStorage.setItem('lang', lang)
    }

    const setToken = (value) => {
        // setCookie('token', value)
        localStorage.setItem('token', value)
        _setToken(value)
    }

    const setIsOpen = () => {
        _setIsOpen((prevState) => !prevState)
    }
   
    return (
        <context.Provider
            value={{
                theme,
                toggleTheme,
                toggleLang,
                token,
                setToken,
                setIsOpen,
                isOpen,
            }}>
            {children}
        </context.Provider>
    )
}

export default MainContextProvider

_document.js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
        const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet()
        const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage
    
        try {
            // Run the React rendering logic synchronously
            ctx.renderPage = () =>
                originalRenderPage({
                    // Useful for wrapping the whole react tree
                    enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
                        sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
                    // Useful for wrapping in a per-page basis
                    enhanceComponent: (Component) => Component,
                })

            // Run the parent `getInitialProps`, it now includes the custom `renderPage`
            const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
            const theme = ctx.req?.cookies?.theme || 'dark'
            const lang = ctx.req?.cookies?.lang
            const dir = lang === 'en' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl'
            
            return {
                ...initialProps,
                theme,
                dir,
                styles: [initialProps.styles, sheet.getStyleElement()]
            }
        }
        finally {
            sheet.seal()
        } }
    render() {
        return (
            <Html className={this.props.theme} dir={this.props.dir}>
                <Head />
                <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        )}}

export default MyDocument

_app.js
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import Providers from '@/components/layout/Providers'
import { getCookie, setCookie } from 'cookies-next'
import MainLayout from '@/components/layout/main/MainLayout'
import { GlobalStyles } from '@/styles/styled/GlobalStyle.styled'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps, theme, ...rest }) {
    // TODO: if cookie is empty
    let _theme = theme
    if (!_theme) {
        _theme = 'dark'
        setCookie('theme', _theme)
    }

    return (
        <Providers theme={_theme} {...rest}>
            <MainLayout pageProps={pageProps}>
                <GlobalStyles />
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </MainLayout>
        </Providers>
    )
}

App.getInitialProps = ({ ctx }) => {
    const theme = getCookie('theme', ctx)
    const token = getCookie('token', ctx)

    return {
        theme,
        token,
    }
}

How can I rewrite the cookie to local-storage, considering that the login should be done at the moment of landing page rendering?

I see a design issue here.
Session is to make api accessible to the user.
For anything UI related you have state.
Instead of trying to pass the session around, try to think it in terms of:

how to send session on each api call (cookies maybe, as you no longer need to worry about attaching session on each api call)
what to do if an api call fails with a 401 (have a state in app, isLoggedIn, and redirect the user to login if its false)

